# Simpletest and examples module

Tags: 7, testing

I've enabled [SimpleTest module](https://drupal.org/project/simpletest) and simpletest_example module in the [Examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples)

I've cleared all caches and i do not see anything about simpletest_example in this page : `admin/config/development/testing`

[SimpleTest Tutorial (Drupal 7)](https://drupal.org/node/890654) : something i've missed ?

Comment: If you did everything just the way docs say, it might be a bug in examples.

Comment: What version of drupal and simpletest are you using?

Comment: I do use the last stables for both (D7 7.23, SimpleTest 7.2.0). It's weird because none of .test files brings any available test in all the Example's submodules

Comment: Year and half later I have the same problem.